# how to send two string array data through handler android

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

I am retrieving data from URL and showing in list view  for that I am getting Json array from website which contains a table with two columns so that I am adding to two string arrays  after that I am setting in adapter.Main problem is I am doing in background thread after that I am sending to handler.I am able to send only one string array only.How can I send two string arrays

```
//background thread    
JSONArray json=new JSONArray(result);
JSONObject jo = null;
list1=new String[json.length()];
list2=new String[json.length()];

for(int i=0; i<json.length(); i++) {
    jo = json.getJSONObject(i);
    list1[i] = jo.getString("studentname");
    list2[i] =  jo.getString("sno");
} 

//handler for send data
Message msg=new Message();
msg.obj=list1;
handler.sendMessage(msg);
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably a bit late to the party, but you could attach the string arrays to a data bundle and attach that bundle to the handler message.

Something like this

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putStringArray("key1", list1);
bundle.putStringArray("key2", list2);

Message message = new Message();
message.setData(bundle);
handler.sendMessage(message);
```

Then you just go ahead and unbundle the arrays at the receiving side and you should be good to go